Geographical representation of (italian) data
I've started a (unpaid mandatory) intership and they basically gave me a massive csv sheet with uncleaned data to make sense of. I managed to clean it up and I now have created a SQL database with all the info, and I would love to get a geographical representation of the data, which looks like this:



Progr
Periodo  comp
Class.azienda
Comune
Provincia
Regione
ateco




189923
2023-03-01
DITTA
Canicattì
Agrigento
Sicilia
47.52.2



I would like to represent the data geographically (by province, or region, or even better with a choropleth map) but excel or google sheet don't seem to be working with my input: google sheets says the data is incompatible, excel says "chek your data and try again". Would anyone be able to point me to ANYTHING at all that would work with this? I can use python, sql and I'm a pretty quick learner (albeit still kind of a newb to all of this). Thanks!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm, step 1 - find the problem column.

have you tried https://www.datawrapper.de/maps/choropleth-map

@BartMcEndree no I haven't, by the looks of it seems exactly what I need. I'll try it out and let you know, many thanks!


There are sites like datawrapper.de dedicated to importing data and making choropleth maps. You can upload your data as CSV, Excel, Link to external data, or connect to a google sheet. I was able to generate a low rez image without even signing-up. I guess if you sign-up they try to up-sell you on the hi-rez interactive versions of the maps.

That looks exactly what I need, thanks, I had a minor health scare so I haven't had the time to try it yet, once I do I'll accept the answer :) Thanks again

It works almost perfectly, although I need to understand how to make it recognize the italian city names. Cheers.
